# Why daysBetween is wrong here?

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to calculate the number of days between two dates like this:

```
public static int getDaysBetweenTwoDates(final LocalDateTime oldDate,
        final LocalDateTime newDate) {
    System.out.println("--Calculate days between: " + oldDate.toString()
            + "->" + newDate);
    Days days = Days.daysBetween(new DateMidnight(oldDate.toDateTime()),
            new DateMidnight(newDate.toDateTime()));
    System.out.println("----DIFF: " + days.size());
    return days.size();
}
```

Well, I can't understand why between 10th December and 28th December it returns "1" as result:

```
--Calculate days between: 2011-12-10T00:00:00.000->2011-12-28T12:01:07.577
----DIFF: 1
```

Do you see any reason?

Update: I've also tried to keep it simple but it still does not work:

```
Days days = Days.daysBetween(oldDate, newDate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `days.getDays()`. According to the [JavaDoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseSingleFieldPeriod.html#size%28%29) of `size()` in `BaseSingleFieldPeriod` (which is the super class of `Days`):

> Gets the number of fields that this period supports, which is one.

Comment: @CristianBoariu you should mark his answer if it was helpful like you sau

Answer (score 0):

Convert both the days in millisecond and get the difference between them in millisecond and divide the difference with `(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` to get the days difference between two calendar dates

**Example**

```
void getDiff(){
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar1.set(2011, 01, 10);
      calendar2.set(2011, 03, 01);
     long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
      long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
      long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
       long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
       System.out.println("...Difference in days..."+diffDays);
}
```